# Can someone help me understand why in this datasheet the Vcm vs Vout curve(or the 'diamond curve') is specified for 'all gains'?

Tags: datasheet, instrumentation-amplifier, common-mode

From what I read so far and from the equations used for deriving the diamond plot for instrumentation amplifier, the shape of the plot changes with gain. Following is an example:

[image]

However, in the datasheet for INA333, the plot specifies, for all gains(shown below). Can someone please explain how can one plot be drawn for all gains?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first plot indicates that the functional limits what the circuit can drive at various common-mode voltages depends on the gain. Often, the mechanism for this is the saturation of internal stages within the amplifier.

Depending on the design of the circuit, the gain might not necessarily influence the achievable common-mode and output ranges. The second plot is not unexpected, it just means that the amplifier is able to swing to the given output range as a function of the common-mode voltage, regardless of how its gain is configured, or that the manufacturer guarantees that range by specification even if some values of gain allow wider ranges of output.

Meanwhile, the first amplifier has a subcircuit whose ability to tolerate large common-mode voltages depends on the configured gain, and when the gain is near 1, that subcircuit begins to limit the achievable output with smaller magnitudes of common-mode voltage.